# logcat filtering tags with special characters

Tags: android, adb, logcat

is it possible with logcat to filter on tags with special characters? This is from a 3rd party SDK, so I can't simply change the tag being logged.

The tag is **[FYB]**
The usual command of

```
adb logcat -s [FYB]
```

doesnt produce any output. I've tried escaping the brackets, but without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do this is by piping it to another utility that can handle escaped characters, like grep.

`adb logcat | grep '\[FYB\]'`